# How do you declare an array of numbers in oracle pl/sql 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a set of numbers that i need to use in 2 queries. these are part of the same oracle SQL script for a 11g server:

update table1 set some_column = 1 where user_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

update table2 set some_other_column = 17 where user_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

How do you factor out that list of numbers into a variable and use it in both update statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005):

```
declare
  type t_num is table of number;
  num t_num;
begin
  -- fill collection from query
  select rownum 
    bulk collect into num
    from dual connect by level < 10;

  -- add one value to collection 
  num.extend;
  num(num.last) := 345;

  -- using in an UPDATE statement (the same you can use in INSERT and DELETE)
  forall i in num.first..num.last 
    update table1 set some_column = 1 where user_id = num(i);
end;
```